# Split by regex on multiple line

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a file document who contains my messages.

I would like to make a split for each message but the format is terrible.

> Date: Nov 27 2019 08:35am
>
> From: dsad (123)
>
> Message-Id: 1231
>
> Subject: Hi
>
> Hello1
>
> Date: Nov 27 2019 08:35am
>
> From: dsad (123)
>
> Message-Id: 1232
>
> Subject: Hi
>
> Hello2
>
> Date: Nov 27 2019 08:35am
>
> From: dsad (123)
>
> Message-Id: 1233
>
> Subject: Hi
>
> Hello3

How I can extract the data ?

Something like

```
private Message {
    DateTime date;
    int fromID;
    int messageID;
    string fromUsername;
    string subject;
    string message;
}

foreach (Message message in messages.Split([...]))
{
    Console.WriteLine(message.messageID);
}
```

What is the best way to achieve that?

I would like to split on the regex

Date: DATETIME

From: STRING (INT)

Message-Id: INT

Subject: STRING ONE ROW

MESSAGES ON MULTIPLE ROW UNTIL NEXT DATE TIME ROW

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, each new segment starts with the keyword 'Date', then each has all the rest of the segments?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regex pattern that encompasses an entire message (tested at https://www.myregextester.com/index.php):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"
  Date:\s+(?<date>[^\r\n]*)[\r\n]+
  From:\s+(?<fromUsername>.*?)\s+\((?<fromID>\d+)\)[\r\n]+
  Message-Id:\s+(?<messageID>\d+)[\r\n]+
  Subject:\s+(?<subject>[^\r\n]*)[\r\n]+
  (?<message>[^\r\n]*)
", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var messages = regex.Matches(...);
```

The named capture groups can then help you extract the details you need.